# Javascript promise. Why does resolve return different values when it's called in different places?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, scope, resolve

```
const image = document.querySelector('.images');

const createImage = (imgPath, seconds) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (imgPath) {
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      setTimeout(() => {
        img.src = imgPath;
        image.append(img);
        resolve(img);
      }, 1000 * seconds);
    } else reject('ERROR. REJECTED');
  });
};

let currentImage;

createImage('./img/img-1.jpg', 1)
  .then(img => {
    console.log(img);
    // img.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('1 successful');
    // img.style.display = 'none';
    return createImage('./img/img-2.jpg', 2);
  })
  .then(img => {
    console.log(img);
    img.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('2 successful');
    return createImage('./img/img-3.jpg', 3);
  })
  .then(img => {
    img.style.display = 'none';
    console.log('3 successful');
    return img;
  });
```

I'm trying to display first picture then hide it to display a second picture after 2 seconds later. Then, hide the second picture to display a third picture.

When I use resolve(imp) inside of setTimeout function, it returns `<img src="./img/img-1.jpg>`.
When resolve(img) is placed outside of setTimeout, it returns just `<img>`. Why are each case return values different? because in JS, we can still use values that was called inside of function even after they are executed and disappeared.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    img.src = imgPath;
    image.append(img);
  }, 1000 * seconds);
  resolve(img);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the difference is: do you add the `src` first and then log, or do you log first and then set the `src`. In both cases, the browser will log the element as it appears at the time of the log statement (at least in chrome -- different browsers may log slightly differently). If the element has an `src`, the log reflects that. If the element has no `src` yet, the log has no src.

This can be demonstrated without involving promises at all:

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
console.log(img);
img.src = 'example';
```

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'example';
console.log(img);
```

So adding the promises back in: if you resolve the promise before you've added an `src`, code execution moves to the `.then` callback and logs it out, with no src. A second later, the `src` gets added, too late to be included in the log. If instead, you wait until the `src` has been added and then resolve the promise, then the code in the `.then` callback can log out the `src`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However I still don't get it. In both case of my code, resolve is called after adding .src and appending img variable. The differences between those cases is either resolve is used inside or outside of setTimeout.

Comment: `In both case of my code, resolve is called after adding .src and appending img variable.` In both cases it's on a *later line*, but the order of execution is quite different. `setTimeout` says "please run the following function in 1 second". The browser takes note of your request, and then **immediately** moves on to the next line.  So your second example queues up a function to run in 1 second, then immediately resolves the promise, and only a second later does it set the src. The first example has all that code run at the one second mark; none of it runs immediately.